# iOS Image Resize

Tags: ios, uiimage

I want to compress a (900 * 900) picture to (600*600) on an iPhone 6 plus.

If I use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(600, 600), NO, 0)
```

the generated UIImage becomes (1800 * 1800).

If I use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), NO, 0)
```

or

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(600, 600), NO, 1)
```

the resulting image will be blurred, which is obviously wrong.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

This is the code

```
- (UIImage*)imageByScalingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize withSourceImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage
{
    UIImage *newImage = nil;
    //Omit scaledWidth/scaledHeight calculation
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetSize.height;
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, NO, 0);
    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    thumbnailRect.size.width= scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;
    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Show your actual, relevant code showing how you attempt to resize the image.

Comment: I'm reedit the question.

Comment: Do you want the `targetSize` to be the number of pixels or the number of points of the resulting image?

Comment: I want image size is (600,600), no scale, and no distortion

Comment: @ch.chay There is no such thing as a UIImage with "no scale".

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib!

UIImage+Zoom.h

```js
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

enum {
    enSvResizeScale,            // image scaled to fill
    enSvResizeAspectFit,        // image scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    enSvResizeAspectFill,       // image scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be cliped
};
typedef NSInteger SvResizeMode;

@interface UIImage (Zoom)

- (UIImage*)resizeImageToSize:(CGSize)newSize resizeMode:(SvResizeMode)resizeMode;

@end
```

UIImage+Zoom.m

```js
#import "UIImage+Zoom.h"

@implementation UIImage (Zoom)

/*
 * @brief resizeImage
 * @param newsize the dimensions（pixel） of the output image
 */
- (UIImage*)resizeImageToSize:(CGSize)newSize resizeMode:(SvResizeMode)resizeMode
{
    CGRect drawRect = [self caculateDrawRect:newSize resizeMode:resizeMode];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, 0.8);

    [self drawInRect:drawRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

// caculate drawrect respect to specific resize mode
- (CGRect)caculateDrawRect:(CGSize)newSize resizeMode:(SvResizeMode)resizeMode
{
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height);

    CGFloat imageRatio = self.size.width / self.size.height;
    CGFloat newSizeRatio = newSize.width / newSize.height;

    switch (resizeMode) {
        case enSvResizeScale:
        {
            // scale to fill
            break;
        }
        case enSvResizeAspectFit:                    // any remain area is white
        {
            CGFloat newHeight = 0;
            CGFloat newWidth = 0;
            if (newSizeRatio >= imageRatio) {        // max height is newSize.height
                newHeight = newSize.height;
                newWidth = newHeight * imageRatio;
            }
            else {
                newWidth = newSize.width;
                newHeight = newWidth / imageRatio;
            }

            drawRect.size.width = newWidth;
            drawRect.size.height = newHeight;

            drawRect.origin.x = newSize.width / 2 - newWidth / 2;
            drawRect.origin.y = newSize.height / 2 - newHeight / 2;

            break;
        }
        case enSvResizeAspectFill:
        {
            CGFloat newHeight = 0;
            CGFloat newWidth = 0;
            if (newSizeRatio >= imageRatio) {        // max height is newSize.height
                newWidth = newSize.width;
                newHeight = newWidth / imageRatio;
            }
            else {
                newHeight = newSize.height;
                newWidth = newHeight * imageRatio;
            }

            drawRect.size.width = newWidth;
            drawRect.size.height = newHeight;

            drawRect.origin.x = newSize.width / 2 - newWidth / 2;
            drawRect.origin.y = newSize.height / 2 - newHeight / 2;

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return drawRect;
}
```

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
This method will be blurred on 6s plus

Answer (score 0):

> If I use:
>
> ```
> UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(600, 600), NO, 0)
> ```
>
> the generated UIImage becomes (1800 * 1800).

That is not quite true. It's true that the bitmap underlying the image is 1800 by 1800, but that is not the only thing about the image that it's important; the UIImage also has a scale and that scale is 3. Thus, the UIImage is in fact treated (with respect to the screen geometry) as 600 by 600, plus it is triple-resolution to match the triple-resolution of the Plus screen — which is exactly what you want.

(The scaling will work best, of course, if you also *start* with the triple-resolution version of your original image. But that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks, if I save this UIImage to .png , and then look at the details of this .png picture, the picture size is still (1800*1800)

Comment: Yes, because the PNG is generated from the bitmap that underlies the image. It knows nothing of UIImage scale. But what you have made originally is _not_ a PNG; it is a UIImage, and it is 600 by 600. Your question said nothing about a PNG, so if that's crucial, you've asked the question very badly.